# No me reconoce los condicionales

Tags: python, python-3.x, sintaxis

Hice una serie de instrucciones para practicar las funciones logicas, pero al poner la edad o el nombre parece no pasar por las funciones logicas que hago:

```
nombre=str(input("coloca tu nombre: "))
edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))

if nombre==str:
    print("pasemos al siguiente dato")
else nombre==int:
    print("dato no aceptado")

if edad==int:
    print("muchas gracias")
else edad==str:
    print("dato no aceptado")

print(f"bienvenido {nombre},como completaste el fomulario anterior sabemos que tu edad es { edad} ")
print("fin del programa")
```

Comment: No sera `type(nombre)` lo que quieres comparar con str o int?

Comment: la idea que lo puse tipo str, para que solo pueda digitarse letras, pero como no halle como hacerlo me fui a definir funciones logicas. Pero como dije no logro hacer lo que tengo pensado aun

Comment: En un principio ya está evaluando las entradas con los tipos adecuados, no hace falta verificar son de dichos tipos. Por otro lado, tendrías que verificar `if typeof(nombre) == <class 'str'>`

Comment: pero despues al ejecutarlos ambos los puedo completar con numeros y letras y no deberia ser asi... entonces no se que hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En python TODO (o casi todo) es un objeto, incluso hasta un simple entero. ¿Que quiere decir eso?, que cualquier cosa en Python tiene métodos. Veamos:

```
>>> p = 'Hola'
>>> type(p)
<class str> # Aqui indica que p es un objeto de tipo str
>>>
>>> # Podemos acceder a métodos string en p
>>> p.find('o')
1
>>> p.upper()
HOLA
```

Aquí podrás ver un [listado de métodos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) de un objeto string

Por otro lado `str` es el nombre de una función predefinida, que transforma objetos en cadena de caracteres.

```
>>> str(6)
'6'
>>> x = str # Asigna la función a una variable
>>> x(123)
'123'
```

Por consiguiente, cuando comparas una variable con una función, te va a retornar `False`

```
>>> 'Hola' == str
False
```

### Arreglando el código

`input()` devuelve una cadena de caracteres, por lo que es innecesaria la función `str()` en el primer `input`.

La línea `if nombre==str:` no es necesaria porque `nombre` siempre va a ser una cadena. Incluso `"12"` es una cadena válida. Si quieres evaluar que la cadena no tenga ningún caracter número, entonces puedes usar el método `isalpha()`. En este caso se agregó el caracter de espacio y punto, usando la *técnica* de eliminación de ese caracter de la cadena con `str_replace()` ya que `isalpha()` los evalúa como False.

No tiene sentido la linea `if edad == int:` porque en el segundo `input()` hay una conversión a entero `int()`. Si la conversión fallara (por ejemplo, agregar otra cosa que no sean letras), el programa se cerraría abruptamente, por lo que nunca vas a ver el `else` de esa condición. Para ambos casos, la entrada debería ser un string y preguntar en los condicionales si esas cadenas tienen determinados juegos de caracteres.

Nota: Cambié un poco el orden de las instrucciones y algunos diálogos de salida para tener una funcionalidad un poco más [natural].

```
nombre = input("> Coloca tu nombre: ")

nombre_temp = nombre.replace(' ', '') # Incluir espacios
nombre_temp = nombre_temp.replace('.', '') # Incluir punto
if nombre_temp.isalpha():
    print("Pasemos al siguiente dato")
    edad = input("> Coloca tu edad: ")
    if edad.isnumeric():
        print("Muchas gracias")
        print(f"Bienvenido {nombre}, como completaste el fomulario anterior sabemos que tu edad es {edad} ")
    else:
        print("Error, la edad no es un numero")
else:
    print("Hay caracteres no aceptados")

print("Fin del programa")
```

Answer (score 1):

De primera instancia else significa "en caso contrario" esto quiere decir si no se cumple lo primero obligatoriamente tienes que hacer lo que yo te diga, por lo que no tienes que darle una condición al else, aqui te dejo un ejemplo

```
if pelota == redonda:
    print("Excelente todavía puedes seguir jugando")
else:
    print("Mira lo que hiciste, ponchaste la pelota u.u")
```

para poner una condición a un else se utiliza **elif**, esto significa si se cumple la primera condicional pero si se cumple esta haz lo que yo diga

```
if pelota == redonda:
    print("Excelente todavía puedes seguir jugando")
elif pelota==inflable:
    print("O no, se desinfló la pelota pero.. ¡Ve a inflarla para seguir jugando!")
else:
    print("Mira lo que hiciste, ponchaste la pelota u.u")
```

por otro lado lo que debes de utilizar aquí es algo que se conoce como **Try & Except** esto te permite preguntar infinitas veces que se cumpla una funcion hasta que se cumpla la condición que quieres, además en el orden que escribiste las líneas de código no te "enteras" de que colocaste un nombre no valido hasta que colocaste la edad por lo que primero hay que ponerlo en orden

```
nombre=str(input("coloca tu nombre: "))
if nombre==str:
    print("pasemos al siguiente dato")
else:
    print("dato no aceptado")
edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))
if edad==int:
    print("muchas gracias")
else:
    print("dato no aceptado")
print(f"bienvenido {nombre},como completaste el fomulario anterior sabemos que tu edad es { edad} ")
print("fin del programa")
```

ahora en lo que hay que fijarnos en en que es lo que imprime, como tu ya viste no cumple las condicionales y al final no le importa si no se cumplen te imprime el mensaje de bienvenida, en realidad las condiciones si se realizan pero no planteaste bien las condiciones. primero te voy a mostrar cuales debían de ser las condicionales y despues te voy a mostrar como implementar el **Try & Except**
por una parte al usar

```
nombre=str(input("coloca tu nombre: "))
edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))
```

no dejas que la consola "piense" ya que sin importar lo que pongas como input luego lo va a transformar en str o en int ya sea su caso ya que así tu se lo ordenaste.
Algo que te recomiendo mucho es variar y probar, así muchas veces eso te da más visión de lo que está pasando.

ahora lo que queremos comparar es el tipo de tu variable con la condición que tu propongas ya sea que sea int o str

por lo que hay que comparar estos mismo

```
if type(nombre) is str:
if type(edad) is int:
```

ahora un problema que podemos ver aquí es que nada impide que un str contenga un número pero la realidad es que no hay mucho problema en eso.
ahora utilizando **Try & Except**, esto se utiliza mucho para salir de loops infinitos y eso es lo que queremos lograr, que pregunte infinitas veces hasta que llene bien el formulario.
Primero para hacer un loop infinito se utiliza *while True:* con la T MAYÚSCULA y es aquí cuando utilizamos el Try. Si te diste cuenta al usar *edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))* y no era entero te marcaba un ValueError y eso es lo que vamos a utilizar

```
while True:
    try:
        edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("tu edad debe de ser un número entero, por favor vuelve a intentar")
```

como podrás ver no te he contado nada de ese break, precisamente gracias a el podemos salir del loop, esto se podría leer como intenta preguntar su edad y si no nos da un valor entero dale unas instrucciones y deja que vuelva a responder

con todo esto ya corregido nuestro código terminaría así

```
nombre=(input("coloca tu nombre: "))

if type(nombre) is str:
    print("pasemos al siguiente dato")
else:
    print("dato no aceptado")

while True:
    try:
        edad=int(input("coloca tu edad: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("tu edad debe de ser un número entero, por favor vuelve a intentar")
print("muchas gracias")


print(f"bienvenido {nombre},como completaste el fomulario anterior sabemos que tu edad es {edad} ")
print("fin del programa")
```

de este modo al imprimir la bienvenida no imprimira datos fallidos ya que tu te habrás encargado de que registre los correctos.
Espero que esto te haya servido de utilidad y sigue practicando condicionales!

Comment: Muy buena explicación :)

Answer (score 0):

Mira el siguiente código:

```
nombre = "Juan"
edad = 10

if nombre == str:
    print("nombre es un string")
else:
    print("error 1")

if edad == int:
    print("edad es un entero")
else:
    print("error 2")

if type(nombre) is str:
    print("nombre es de tipo string")

if type(edad) is int:
    print("edad es de tipo entero")
```

produce

```
error 1
error 2
nombre es de tipo string
edad es de tipo entero
```

Cuando dices `nombre == str`, lo que haces es comparar la variable `nombre` (que contiene un string) con la función Python `str`, lo que siempre va a ser `False`. Igual con `edad` e `int`.

Cuando dices `type(nombre) is str` estas preguntando si `nombre` es una variable de tipo string, lo que en este caso es verdadero.

La confusión surge debido a que Python interpreta de manera distinta el lexema `str`. En la primera comparación, Python considera `str` como el nombre de una función. En la segunda, `str` es el nombre de un tipo de datos.

**Caso general**

La expresión `type(var)` también funciona con clases que tú hayas definido. Ejemplo:

```
class MiPropiaClase:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

a = MiPropiaClase(5)

print("Tipo de a", type(a))

if type(a) == MiPropiaClase:
    print("a es de tipo MiPropiaClase")
```

produce

```
Tipo de a <class '__main__.MiPropiaClase'>
a es de tipo MiPropiaClase
```

Fijate que `type(a)` lo tienes que comparar con el *nombre de la clase*, sin usar paréntesis.